# unable to execute ModuleNotFoundError in terminal . But work in pycharm ide

Tags: python, pycharm

I am learning python

I have project structure shown below.

```
i3cmd
    i3lib
      __init__.py
      i3common.py
    i3sound
      i3sound.py
```

==============================================================

**init**.py is empty

i3common.py (removed actual code to simplify the post)

```
def rangeofdata(cmd, device, index):
    return ["a", "b", "c"]
```

i3sound.py (removed actual code to simplify the post)

```
from i3lib import i3common


def getvolume(rangedata):
    return rangedata


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rangedata = i3common.rangeofdata(["pactl", "list", "sinks"], "Sink", 2)
    print(getvolume(rangedata))
```

When execute this code in pycharm it execute and get output

```
/home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd/venv/bin/python /home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd/i3sound/i3sound.py
['a', 'b', 'c']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when open a terminal and go to /home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd/i3sound

```
cd /home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd/i3sound
```

then execute

```
python i3sound.py
```

below error i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i3sound.py", line 1, in <module>
    from i3lib import i3common
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'i3lib'
```

What i am missing?

Comment: You might have installed the package 'i3lib' in the environment where you run the project in Pycharm.

Comment: Niks As i explained it is not a global module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey @Vipin here is what you need to do:

in i3sound.py add these lines: `import sys`, `sys.path.append("..")`

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append("..")
    from i3lib import i3common


    def getvolume(rangedata):
        return rangedata


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rangedata = i3common.rangeofdata(["pactl", "list", "sinks"], "Sink", 2)
        print(getvolume(rangedata))
```

output:
        ['a', 'b', 'c']

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the package 'i3lib' in the environment where you run the project in Pycharm.

You can create a virtual environment by using:

```
virtualenv .venv
```

Activate virtual environment:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

and install i3lib by:

```
pip install i3lib
```

and then enter python shell.

Comment: as i explained  i3lib is a package in my project. And also i explained my project structure in my Post. So you mean to say i. Need to install i3lib as a seperate global packages. Can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Because: i3lib is not in /home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd/i3sound but in /home/vipin/Documents/python/i3cmd...............................if you don't get it yet let me know such that i will post solved version of your sample code.

Comment: @Abdirahman Can you please give more detail in answer section. Also can you help me to resolve this.

Comment: I will post it as answer when i get home two hours ltr may be if there is no approved answers till that.